# Integrate Amazon Lex with Voice assistant

Tags: amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-lex

Could anyone please suggest the possible approaches to integrate Amazon lex with any voice assistants. Requirement is to provide the hands-free interaction instead of text.

Thanks,
Vempati

Answer (score 3):

Since you are using Amazon Lex, it is almost always easiest to integrate with another Amazon product.

So I suggest using [Amazon Connect](https://aws.amazon.com/connect/). It has a really simple drag and drop building of the interaction flow:

[image]

---

Then that "Get customer input" block, has a simple toggle for integrating with your Lex bot:

---

[image]

---

From there, your Lex bot will take over and any messages that would normally be delivered as text, are automatically converted to voice. You have some options for which voice to use too, several male and female versions.

And it's very easy to pass `sessionAttributes` between Connect and Lex.